# Approach to solve a not accurate replay system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to make accurate replay system in unity and c#

Hi all,
Im working on a racing game and I decided to add a replay system to allow "ghost car" too, initially I was recordng data in some events like key pressed but only recording that data in all frames I manage a smooth replay, well its still ok as file is not huge and replay works, but the trouble is there is always a slight variation in time, only like 0.1 seconds or 0.2 at the most, I have a list of keyframes and in each position I record a time to be shown, the trouble I think is that because fps vary then not in all runs the same time marks are shown then the winning frame's time is not always being rendered so the winning frame happens in next update slightly after it should be shown. Im using c# and unity just in case, but I think its independent to this mainly. Thanks a lot about any clue, I have been around this issue for some time now

Comment: In general, if your simulation is not deterministic, you're gonna have problems if you only record the inputs.

Comment: yes you are right, trying to record few data is making it not look right, still the main problem remains on making the time accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing frame-by-frame replay which, as you've discovered, requires your frames to play back with the same delay as the recording.  In a game-render loop, that's not guaranteed to happen.

As you record the car states (position, heading, etc) per frame, you need to also record a timestamp (in this case, accumulating `Time.deltaTime` from race start should suffice).

When you play it back, find the current timestamp and interpolate (ie, `Lerp`) the car's state from the recorded bounding frames.

Hints for frame interpolation:

```
class Snapshot {
    public float Timestamp;

    public Matrix4x4 Transform;  // As an example.  Put more data here.
}

private int PrevIndex = 0;

private List<Snapshot> Snapshots = (new List<Snapshot>()).OrderBy(m => m.Timestamp).ToList();

private float GetLerpFactor(float currentTimestamp) {

    if ( PrevIndex == Snapshots.Count - 1) 
        return 0; // Reached end of Snapshots

    while (currentTimestamp >= Snapshots[PrevIndex + 1].Timestamp)
        PrevIndex++; // move 'frame' forward

    var currentDelta = Mathf.Max(0f, currentTimestamp - Snapshots[PrevIndex].Timestamp);
    var fullDelta = Snapshots[PrevIndex + 1].Timestamp - Snapshots[PrevIndex].Timestamp;

    var lerpFactor = currentDelta / fullDelta;
    return lerpFactor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and code, yes I think thats the way it should be done, but also the time the ghost car is crossing the  goal should be faked I think, I mean even interpolating between frames its possible that the time when it should be crossing the line is not being rendered and it crosses a little after that.

Comment: @asdronin If your replay is only out by a couple of frames (ie, a few milliseconds), 'faking' the time won't affect your user's experience at all.  A perfectly reasonable compromise =)

Comment: I think you are right and it wont affect the player experience =), I noticed that at the start of the race it could be noticeable as most of us step on gas when the countdown is going on so seeing the ghost not starting at same high speed can be seen, but almost removed that delay making the ghost car go and show the timestamp that is either the same or a little above the recorded keyframe skipping some, as you know I was having 2 frames of delay so I remove that delay as soon as its noticed. Thanks a lot really, the game will be out soon, feel free to check out soon for "Speed Masters ASD" =)

Answer (score 1):

Unless for some reason you need to interact with "ghost" car (like collisions) record final data on position/speed/direction at frequent enough original moments of time and interpolate that to new simulation. I would not record raw inputs but rather resulting changes (like gear shifts) unless you need to measure/show how fast user reacted to something.

If you really want to replay the same inputs you'd have to run two separate simulations at the same time so physics and timing of "real" version don't impact "ghost" one, most likely you'll have to again interpolate output of "ghost" simulation to align with real one (unless you have fixed time steps).

Comment: Yes you are right I dont need to interact with ghost car, just race against it with collisions diabled between ghost and player. I tried recording as you said and yet the problem remains, I mean I cant make the arriving time match the original arriving time its almost always slightly different due to frame skip. Im currently recording a lot of data but later I will just record few like you said though yet I want to fix time inconsistence first

Comment: @asdronin I don't understand what you have problem with... If your original car has (pos=1, time =5), (pos=4, time = 11) and you trying to render frame at (time=7,9,13) than you never will see it at the pos=4 (finish line) as you get (pos=2, t=7), (pos=3, t=9), (pos=5, t=13)… If you want to see it at pos=4 you'll need to make your real simulation to render frame at t =11...

Comment: yes thats the problem, but even if I pick data to replay on every frame I cant assure the right time is going to be rendered, so system registers a different time for ghost track time almost each time I playback it, of course I could fake it and say well the ghost arrived at the same time it was recorded the first time (write in the file the time) but I dont feel its fair for the player as maybe he sees himself winning for a fraction of a second when result tells he lost, well considering its only like 0.2 at maximum maybe its not noticeable but I wanted to make it right